# Django DEBUG=False does not serve media files, thumbnails or thumbnails

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm working on an application that when set to production mode (`DEBUG=False`) does not load image thumbnails, when `DEBUG=True` loads and displays normally, static files are also loaded normally in production when the command `python3 manage. py collectstatic`

`Settings.py`

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

`urls.py`

```
...
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
...
```

Comment: Do you really have a space in `manage. py`?

Answer (score 0):

found the answer

```
    from django.urls import re_path
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    from django.views.static import serve

    urlpatterns = [

        re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),

]


    # urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

This re_path function can request all MEDIA_ROOT files in settings.py